# htaccess: rewrite query string to path

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a domain with the following query string:

```
http://example.com/?taxo=question&cata=foo&catb=bar&catc=more
```

My objective is to convert this query string after `?taxo=` into a path based on the values for each parameter like so:

```
http://example.com/questions/cata/foo/catb/bar/catc/more/
```

Using `.htaccess`, this is what I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^taxo=(.*)&(.*)=(.*)&(.*)=(.*)&(.*)=(.*)$  $1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7 [L,R=301]
```

However, that doesn't work for me. I'm trying to understand where I am going wrong with the `RewriteRule` line since the condition isn't being met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string in a `RewriteRule`. You should use `QUERY_STRING` variable in a `RewriteCond` to match and capture value from query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^taxo=([^&]+)&([^=]+)=([^&]+)&([^=]+)=([^&]+)&([^=]+)=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/%6/%7? [L,R=301]
```

- Note that you will need to use `%N` syntax for back-reference of values captured in `RewriteCond`.
- `?` at the end of the target URI is to strip off previous query string.